# javascript only working remotely on tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this problem might just be really small, but I just can't figure it out. I am currently working on my own tumblr theme, but the question might just not have much to do with tumblr.

The thing I try to do is a for loop that checks if pictures are smaller than 500px wide. Then I want to adjust the divs containing the smaller images so they have a background and a border. This is the html and the script:

```
<div class="photo">
  <div class="image">
   <img class="post-image" alt="alt" src="img-source">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('post-image');
  for (var i=0, c=0; i<elements.length, c<element.length; i++, c++) {
    if ($(elements[i]).width() < 499){
      $(element[c]).css({
        'padding-top'   :   16 + 'px',
        'padding-bottom':   10 + 'px',
        'background'    :   '#222222',
        'border'        :   1 + 'px solid #353535'
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

It all works in the 'Edit Theme' Part of tumblr. But it doesnt on the actual blog. Perhaps somebody here can help me figure it out? And yes I included the JQuery Api in the header.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console on the live site? Could you provide a link so we can test?

Comment: I don't get any errors no and.. well.. my tumblr blog is very sexually oriented so I am unsure if I even am 'allowed' to post it here?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Tumblt. But might they strip all your javascript code away for safety reasons?

Comment: As long as you include a warning with the link, it should be all right.

Comment: You can definitely use Javascript in Tumblr themes.

Comment: Since I got an answer now and it works I don't need to post my blog :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine when I enter it through the console, so I'm gonna take a stab and say it's called too early. You need to wait for the page to finish loading, then do the code. Since you've got jQuery, it's as simple as this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('post-image');
    for (var i = 0, c = 0; i < elements.length, c < element.length; i++, c++) {
        if ($(elements[i]).width() < 499) {
            $(element[c]).css({
                'padding-top': 16 + 'px',
                'padding-bottom': 10 + 'px',
                'background': '#222222',
                'border': 1 + 'px solid #353535'
            });
        }
    }
});
```